# Parsley JS - Validate if input is empty (one of two fields needs to be entered)

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, parsley.js

I am creating a dynamic form that has three inputs per line (row). The inputs are all text fields. When I add another row it adds three more inputs to the overall form.

Having two inputs on each line is important and I need at least one of them to be filled in. The third input field is not that important and I do not care if it is validated using Parsley.

I was thinking of checking each of the two inputs on a single row is valid before adding another line. However, I cannot seem to find any documentation on if Parsley supports conditional validation (it appears I would need to customize it and I would prefer not to).

A solution would be to add the required fields to each of the inputs. When a user adds a value to the input it would remove the required attribute from the other cell and so on. I would rather use a Parsley function to do so, but I can't seem to find one.

If anyone has any ideas/suggestions, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Check http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/custom-validator-events.html